# Connecting desktop to a Chromebook for realtime playing

Tags: networking, streaming, remote-access, gaming

I've got a desktop Linux computer with an RTX 4080 and an Acer Spin 713 CP713-2W-5719 Chromebook. Spring is here, so I'd like to play my games and enjoy the nice weather on the balcony (about 20m away) at the same time.

My desktop is currently connected to 5GHz wifi via a tethered Android phone (I'm upcycling it as a wifi card), and I'd like to try [Sunshine](https://docs.lizardbyte.dev/projects/sunshine/en/latest/about/overview.html)/[Moonlight](https://moonlight-stream.org/) as my software streaming solution.

What should I do on the hardware side to make it work?

One solution I am thinking of getting an Ethernet-to-USB adapter and a 20m/65ft USB-C cable. Would that work? If no, what is a better setup?

Comment: Do you have better Internet (ISP) where you are? Add a wireless AP.

Comment: Ethernet travels further than USB & is far cheaper.

Comment: Alright, so a 20m Ethernet cable then with an Ethernet-to-USB adapter at the end to plug into the Chromebook?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You have a software product, and this should document it's requirements. Are you asking for general advice, or do you have a specific problem that needs to be solved?

Comment: I'm asking if the hardware setup - a 20m cable - would work in this case. Do you think that's doable?